# inserting row into UItableView error

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, alamofire

I Have tableView that gived data from url api by 10 items. When it scroll to down I try to get next 10 items and insert them into row.
So in viewDidload I get

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, urlQuery, parameters: ["universityId": UBUniversitySettings.getUniversityId(), "page" : currentPage, "pageSize" : 10]).responseJSON{ (request, response, JSON, error) in
            println(JSON)
            var newsResponse = JSON! as NSArray
            for newsItemResponse in newsResponse{
                var newsItem:NewsModel = NewsModel()
                newsItem.newsImage = newsItemResponse.valueForKey("previewPic") as? String
                newsItem.newsTitle = newsItemResponse.valueForKey("title") as? String
                newsItem.newsDescription = newsItemResponse["content"] as? String
                newsItem.newsId = newsItemResponse["id"] as? String
                self.tableViewNews.addObject(newsItem)

               // self.newsTableView.reloadData()
                self.newsTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet.init(index: 0), withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom )


            }
            self.currentPage = self.currentPage + 1

        }
```

and in

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if(indexPath.row == self.currentPage * 10  - 1){
        self.getNextNews()
    }
}
```

i get next items

```
func getNextNews(){
    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlQuery, parameters: ["universityId": UBUniversitySettings.getUniversityId(), "page" : currentPage, "pageSize" : 10]).responseJSON{ (request, response, JSON, error) in
        println(JSON)
        var newsResponse = JSON! as NSArray
        if(newsResponse.count > 0){
            var newsIndex:NSInteger = 0
            var paths:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
            for newsItemResponse in newsResponse{

                var newsItem:NewsModel = NewsModel()
                newsItem.newsImage = newsItemResponse.valueForKey("previewPic") as? String
                newsItem.newsTitle = newsItemResponse.valueForKey("title") as? String
                newsItem.newsDescription = newsItemResponse["content"] as? String
                newsItem.newsId = newsItemResponse["id"] as? String
                self.tableViewNews.addObject(newsItem)

                // self.newsTableView.reloadData()
                self.newsTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet.init(index: 0), withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom )
                var indexPathVal = self.currentPage * 10 + newsIndex

                var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPathVal as Int, inSection: 0)
                paths.addObject(indexPath)
                newsIndex = newsIndex + 1

            }
            self.newsTableView.reloadData()
            self.newsTableView.beginUpdates()

            self.newsTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(paths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom)
            self.currentPage = self.currentPage + 1
            self.newsTableView.endUpdates()



        }

    }
}

But my app crashed and give me a message
```

Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (11) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (11), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After called `self.newsTableView.reloadData()` tableView already contains new data. And when you try make update:
     self.newsTableView.beginUpdates()
     //code
     self.newsTableView.endUpdates()
Your array is not changed. You should not call reloadData or reloadSections while your array is updating(use insert with animation in the end of function, if you want). Or you should use reloadData or reloadSections without begin/end updates.

Your method should be:

```
 func getNextNews(){
     Alamofire.request(.GET, urlQuery, parameters: ["universityId": UBUniversitySettings.getUniversityId(), "page" : currentPage, "pageSize" : 10]).responseJSON{ (request, response, JSON, error) in
         println(JSON)
         var newsResponse = JSON! as NSArray
         if(newsResponse.count > 0){
             //code
            self.tableViewNews.addObject(newsItem)

            //self.newsTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet.init(index: 0), withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom )

        }
        //self.newsTableView.reloadData()
        self.newsTableView.beginUpdates()

        self.newsTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(paths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom)
        self.currentPage = self.currentPage + 1
        self.newsTableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
}
```

Or:

```
      func getNextNews(){
     Alamofire.request(.GET, urlQuery, parameters: ["universityId": UBUniversitySettings.getUniversityId(), "page" : currentPage, "pageSize" : 10]).responseJSON{ (request, response, JSON, error) in
         println(JSON)
         var newsResponse = JSON! as NSArray
         if(newsResponse.count > 0){
             //code
            self.tableViewNews.addObject(newsItem)

            self.newsTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet.init(index: 0), withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom )

        }
        self.newsTableView.reloadData()
        //self.newsTableView.beginUpdates()

        //self.newsTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(paths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom)
        self.currentPage = self.currentPage + 1
        //self.newsTableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Review your code. Are you returning the correct count of Cells, in your cellinSection?

Also, wrap your insertion code with

```
    [tableView beginUpdate];
// Do insertion here. 
    [tableview endUpdate];
    [tableView reloadData];
```

Whereas in your code, the line

```
self.newsTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet.init(index: 0), withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom )
```

is not wrapped in endUpdate/beginUpdate

And in your last function, your reloadData is outside the wraps as well.

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.tableViewNews.count
    }  here is numberOfRowsInSection  and I have added  self.tableViewNews.addObject(newsItem) to the array. Also in debugger number of rows after update is 11, so I think it ok

Comment: @nabiullinas It also says plus/minus the update, and you have added a row, which when added makes it 12. :)

Comment: If you use only one method for reload/insert sections/row you shouldn't wrap it to begin/end updates

Comment: @iosDev82 hmhmhm, I think I am not understand you correctly=( What I need to do? I added new Item to tableViewNews (dataSource array), and insert new row. So What I miss?

Comment: I found it. I have use self.newsTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet.init(index: 0), withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom )
                in my array in getting data, so it reload data before beginUpdates!! Thankyou =)

Comment: @nabiullinas also close the question.